# Varnish, using URL for backend instead of IP address

Tags: reverse-proxy, varnish-vcl

I started setting up a reversed proxy server with varnish. I'm not experienced setting up varnish.

I am trying to use url of the backend instead of ip address with no luck:

1- Approach a:

```
backend default {
  .host = "www.backend.mysite.com";
  .port = "80";
}
```

Issue a: Restarting varnish keeps failing.

2- Approach b:

```
sub vcl_recv {
set req.http.Host = "www.backend.mysite.com"; 
...
}
```

Issue b: with this approach, when I enter mysite.com in browser bar, it gets redirected to www.backend.mysite.com.

I don't think this is an accepted behavior for this rule. Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks,
Shab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first try should work but your varnish server needs to have access to internet or at least to dns servers.

when you start varnish it will make a dns lookup and replace www.backend.mysite.com by the first ip it is given by dns.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. That answered my question.

Comment: The problem appears when your backend is a name-based virtual server. You can't access it via IP only.